# "longer", "for longer", or "more"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, adverbs

> I wish I had continued to run for longer.
>
> I wish I had continued to run longer.
>
> I wish I had continued to run more.

What is the difference between these, especially semantically?

In my view, the adverb *more* is cover term, isn't it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "cover term".

Comment: I would leave out the "continued to"; i.e.: _I wish I had run longer, I wish I had run more, I wish I had run further, I wish I had pushed myself harder,_ etc. The "continued to" part is implied and seems redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think including ***for*** would ever affect the meaning. Since *continuing to run* is a relatively uncommon activity, let's look at...

> [*slept longer than*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22slept%20longer%20than%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (46,500 hits in Google Books)
>    [*slept **for** longer than*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22White%20to%20play%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22slept%20for%20longer%20than%22&tbm=bks) (979 hits)

I can't say I think there's anything *wrong* with #2 there, but it's worth noting that you can't introduce ***for*** with other ["comparative adverbs"](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adverbials/comparative-adverbs). It's okay with ***longer***, but ...

> - *"I ran **for faster** than you, so I finished first"* (not valid English)

So given that ***for*** longer isn't particularly common anyway, and it doesn't involve a principle which can be extrapolated to other contexts, I'd say it's not really worth learning (except if you need to satisfy yourself that the usage isn't actually "incorrect").